# TypeError:Button object is not callable. Cannot access the attributes of a Button from a __init__ function with another function

Tags: python, function, class, button, tkinter

I have developed a pretty interface for my office with an RasPi and I wanted to polish it but I have come to an dead-end. Basically when someone pressed a button I want that button to get **disabled and to change its background to green**.I have simplified the code for a better helping, but the context is the same.
As you can see **I can disable the printButton with another function**, but somehow it **doesn't let me to change its attributes with the same function which changed its status.**. Can you help me?

```
from tkinter import*


class Buttons:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame=Frame()
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton=Button(frame, text="Print Message", command=self.Message)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton=Button(frame, text="Quit", command=quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def Message(self):
            print("It works ffs")
            self.printButton['state']=DISABLED   #this works fine 
            self.printButton(bg='green')   #when adding this line it gives me that error "TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable"


root=Tk()
b=Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Solved, thanks to Jordan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Message(self):
        print("It works ffs")
        self.printButton['state']=DISABLED   #this works fine
        self.printButton.configure(bg='green')
```